# Running psql command from a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql

I'm having trouble connecting postgresDB to my app using `docker-compose`

My understanding of docker compose is that I can combine two containers so that they can communicate with each other. Suppose I have an app in the `app`container that runs the psql command (just a one liner python script with `os.command("psql")`). Since the `app` container does not have postgres installed, it won't be able to run psql by itself. However, I thought combining two containers in docker-compose.yml would let me run psql but apparently not.

What am I missing here?

I am using 2 postgres images because I'm trying to find regression bugs between two dbms

```
version: "3"
services:
    app:
        image: "app:1.0"
        depends_on: 
            - postgres9
            - postgres12
        ports:
            - 8080:80 
    postgres9:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_DB: test_bd
        ports:
            - '5432:5432'
    postgres12:
        image: postgres:12
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_DB: test_bd
        ports:
            - '5435:5435'
```

Comment: From within the `app` container, you should be able to `telnet postgres9 5432`. What do you get?

Answer (score 3):

Each Docker container has a self-contained filesystem.  You can never directly run commands from the host or from other containers' filesystems; anything you want to run needs to be installed in the container (really, in its image's Dockerfile).

If you want to run a tool like `psql`, it needs to be installed in your image.  You don't say what your base image is, but if it's based on Debian or Ubuntu, you need to install the [`postgresql-client`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/postgresql-client) package:

```sh
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      postgresql-client
```

The right approach here is to add a standard Python PostgreSQL client library, like [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/), to your project's Python `Pipfile`, `setup.py`, and/or `requirements.txt`, and use that library instead of shelling out to `psql`.  You will also need the PostgreSQL C library header files to install that package; instead of `postgresql-client`, install the Debian [`libpq-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libpq-dev) package.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, those two containers with postgres instance in each, are running on different hosts (other than host with `app`). What you need is to specify correct host in `psql` command. It might look like (for postgres12 container):

```sh
PGPASSWORD="mysecretpassword" psql -h postgres12 -d test_bd -U postgres
```